# (Idle Game) offline increment issue and saving this data in a secure way

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on idle game project but the problem is saving offline progression. I also want to be able to keep the same values in the upgrades the way they were when the player exited/offline. I do not want to save using **PlayerPrefs** as its unsecured and allows people to cheat. Anyways I hope someone can give me some sort of direction here. I am not asking for the answer just a pointing hand to guide the way. I have attempted searching for this but did not find any answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think as long as you save locally, its equally unsafe no matter wheter you save it with playerprefs or a more sophisticated method. likewise if you get human-readable plaintext data from a server, it might be easier to manipulate than well encrypted data on your local storage. in short, i think its more about WHAT you save, not WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

The Desired security level is more important than the method of implementation.

Think about it, you want to store data locally, you can not guarantee that your data is not going to be hacked, but you can make it harder for the hacker.

`PlayerPrefs` normally store data in plain text, you can encrypt data and then put the data in it. a huge amount of cheaters cannot read or change it now.

Every encryption algorithm wants a **Key** to encrypt data. you have to put your encryption key inside your client.
You can put it inside your code and create that code in runtime(some math calculations). you can also put your encryption key inside a Unity Scriptable Object, Unity automatically converts this data when in builds the game.

- if you are going to put your encryption key inside your code, then do not forget to obfuscate your code.(an other thing to make hacking harder).

When you done all of this, **I** THINK THIS WILL BE ENOUGH, but again it depends on your desired security level.